# ODM Command Line Build For Classic Rule Projects

Tags: ibm-odm

I am using ODM 8.10 and want to automate building rule app files. The code is currently configured in the old Classic Rule Project, and we are trying to avoid migrating to Decision Services at this time. I have found build jars for Decision Services but nothing so far for Classic Rule Projects. There must be a way to do this as the rule app jar files are created in the eclipse IDE when you deploy/export a ruleApp. I am trying to find out the jar files the IDE uses and the commands it calls to execute the rule app builds.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "*There must be a way to do this*"
But you will not necessarily have access to it. The ODM product developers have experience, source code, documentation, and other tools that you do not have access to.
Having said that, there is an build/deploy API that you may be able to access via ANT. I haven't used it since switching to Decision Services when that became feasible in ODM 8.7. Standard practice before that time was to automate deployments via Ant and a "headless" version of Eclipse. If the latest online docs don't describe it, you might try the older docs.

WARNING: Classic Rule Projects are a dead end! Not only will all your effort building them in a non-standard way be wasted, I believe that it will likely be more trouble than just migrating to Decision Services (which is not usually that difficult).